# Parse received information into columns/rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to get all the data from a Binance and push out parsed information. Here's my script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();

  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.binance.com/assetWithdraw/getAllAsset.html");
  var first = JSON.parse(data)[0];
  var out = JSON.stringify(first).split(",");

  for(var i =0;i<out.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    Logger.log(out[i]);
    ss.getRange(1,i+1).setValue(out[i]);
  }
}
```

I received information that looks like "title":"value". I need to get all the "title" values as column headers and then the values as the rows. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve each data by separating "title" and "values".
- Create an array for importing data to Spreadsheet and import it using `setValues()`.

#### Modified script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.binance.com/assetWithdraw/getAllAsset.html");

  // Modified
  var out = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
  var title = [];
  for (var i in out[0]) {
    title.push(i);
  }
  var res = [];
  res.push(title);
  for (var i in out) {
    var values = [];
    for (var j in out[i]) {
      values.push(out[i][j]);
    }
    res.push(values);
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Reference :

- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit 1 :

In order to retrieve keys from object which is `out[0]`, I used `for (var i in out[0]) {`. Please see the following samples.

#### Sample 1 :

```
var sample = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}];
for (var i in sample[0]) {
  Logger.log("%s, %s", i, sample[0][i])
}
```

Result

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
```

In this script, `sample[0]` is an object of `{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}`. `for (var i in sample[0]) {` can retrieve keys which are `key1` and `key2`. Using retrieved keys, `value1` and `value2` can be retrieved by `sample[0][i]`.

On the other hand, please see the next sample script.

#### Sample 2 :

```
var sample = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}];
for (var i = 0; i < sample[0].length; i++) {
  Logger.log("%s, %s", i, sample[0][i])
}
```

In this script, `sample[0].length` becomes `undefined`. Because `object.length` cannot retrieve the length. So this for loop doesn't work.

If you want to retrieve keys and values using for loop like the sample 2. Please use the next sample script.

#### Sample 3 :

```
var sample = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}];
var keys = Object.keys(sample[0]);
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("%s, %s", keys[i], sample[0][keys[i]])
}
```

Result

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
```

In this script, keys from object can be retrieved by `Object.keys()`. Using this, keys and values are retrieved.

#### Reference :

- [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

### Edit 2 :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.binance.com/assetWithdraw/getAllAsset.html");

  // Modified
  var out = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
  var title = [];
  for (var i in out[0]) {
    if (i == "assetCode" || i == "transactionFee") {
      title.push(i);
    }
  }
  var res = [];
  res.push(title);
  for (var i in out) {
    var values = [];
    for (var j in out[i]) {
      if (j == "assetCode" || j == "transactionFee") {
        values.push(out[i][j]);
      }
    }
    res.push(values);
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: 5 stars, 10 points, and two thumbs up for you! That is PERFECT! Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me understand how this works? I inserted Logger.log(out[0]) at line 24 and then Logger.log(i) in the title.push(i) area. The first returned what appears to be the full output, but the latter only includes the titles. How does this script get rid of the value while keeping the title?
Also - how can I specify certain columns to output, rather than all? For instance, just the Asset Code (column 2) and Transaction Fee (column 5)?

Comment: @Matthew Holland I couldn't understand ``line 24``. So I'm not sure whether I understand your comment correctly. I used ``for (var i in out[0]) {`` to retrieve ``header``. Because all elements have the same title (keys). And then, at ``for (var j in out[i]) {``, ``j`` is keys of each element. Using this, I retrieved each value. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: I understand that it does that, but I've always seen FOR loops used with numerical iterators. You're using the shorthand, but this still looks like it's _supposed_ to mean the same as `for (var i=0;i<out[0].length;i++)` which would mean that at every instance, `i` should be an integer. That doesn't seem to be the case, though, so I'm not sure how to only scrape specific columns.

Comment: @Matthew Holland I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic, don't worry. It's me trying to figure it out! At this point my only question is how can I return specific columns, rather than all? This returns all of them, but what if I just want columns 2 and 5?

Comment: @Matthew Holland I'm sorry for my incomplete answer. I couldn't notice that you want columns 2 and 5. I'm really sorry. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, no reason for apology. I thought about putting the IF() statement in for the title, but couldn't figure out how to get only those columns for the data itself. THANK YOU